# zsh word selection/replacement

Tags: command-line, zsh

I've recently started using [angular-style commit messages](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#commit-message-format):

`<type>(<scope>): <subject>`

I currently just paste the line above into the terminal and then painstakingly select each section to edit it into something like:

`design(password reset form): add field for retina scan`

What I'm hoping to figure out is a way to create a snippet that allows me to jump between the parts of the line that I need to change, auto-selecting the placeholder text so I can just type to replace it.

E.g. I'd type an alias, and something like this would show up:

`$type($scope): $subject`

I hit tab, and `$type` gets selected, I type my replacement text and hit tab and `$scope` gets selected, etc.

The closest I've found in the zsh docs is all about autocompletion, and frankly has me pretty baffled.

Comment: Other than the text you need to edit, the template only contains 4 additional characters. It would seem easier to just type the message from scratch.

Comment: I appreciate that, but there are tons of applications of this workflow if I can get it set up, including some pretty lengthy commands.